# MVC 4 providing JSON string (with date) to jQuery $.ajax() cross-domain (bugs?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I have a basic HTML page using jQuery 1.6.2 and I have an MVC application that serves data on a separate domain (The HTML page is local, the MVC application is not). The MVC application is sending back a JSON string just fine; the problem is that when sending back dates, there are a "/" before and after the date which breaks the JSON string, which in turn does not get turned into a javascript object. Phew.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url:url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR); console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Using the "network" tab in the Chrome profiler, I can see that a JSON string is being returned, and it has the correct data, but has some malformed syntax. Here is a sample of that:

```
"DateAuthorized":"\/Date(1307789505000-0500)\/",
```

I tried to use dataType "text", but because this is a cross-domain request, I have to use jsonp.

Any ideas what-so-ever? Can the MVC application use a regex to remove the slashes? Is there a way to use javascript XHttpRequest to build a manual request?

Agh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using the default serializer which is the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which has always had this issue. An alternative is to use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to serialize your objects.

You can always implement a replacement from the client-side -- [parseJSON extension](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html)

...Or format it from the server-side like this before sending it back:

```
return new DateTime(2012, 4, 19).ToLongDateString(); // or ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: I'm not at work still, but as soon as I get in tomorrow morning I will try extending the function. Thanks!

Comment: Does $.ajax call $.parseJSON on a successful response header?

Comment: Yes, you call $.parseJSON once you've received the JSON data.

Comment: I meant that the $.ajax call must perform some kind of validation on the string before it converts it to an object, right?. 

I don't think I can do anything client-side, so I'll have to go through the right channels to get the application updated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $.ajax doesn't do anything to JSON. The $.parseJSON extension extends the regular deserializer from JSON to object. I highly recommend moving your conversions on the server-side though.

Comment: I agree; the problem is that I'm in a very corporate environment where changes like this come ... very.... slow. It would have just been faster for me to implement a hack to workaround for now.

Thanks for the explanation as well.